# Swift closures with Optional<T> vs ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>

Tags: swift, closures, option-type

So I was experimenting with Swift optionals and implicitly unwrapped optionals:

```
let foo1: Optional<String> = Optional<String>.Some("foo")
let foo2: ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String> = ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String>.Some("foo")
let foo3: ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String> = Optional<String>.Some("foo")
let foo4: Optional<String> = ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String>.Some("foo")

let bar1: (_: Optional<String>) -> () = { (s: Optional<String>) -> () in print(s ?? "nil") }
let bar2: (_: ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String>) -> () = { (s: ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String>) -> () in print(s ?? "nil") }
let bar3: (_: ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String>) -> () = { (s: Optional<String>) -> () in print(s ?? "nil") }
let bar4: (_: Optional<String>) -> () = { (s: ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String>) -> () in print(s ?? "nil") }
```

foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, bar1, bar2 and bar3 compiles and works properly. bar4 throws a compile error:

> /Users/TamasZahola/SwiftTest/SwiftTest/main.swift:19:41: Cannot convert value of type '(ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional) -> ()' to specified type '(Optional) -> ()'

Can anybody explain this? Why does it work when you assign an `(Optional)->()` to `(ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional)->()`, but not in the reversed case?

Comment: I suggest to mention what the compile error says.

Comment: It says it cannot convert (ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String>)->() to (Optional<String>)->().